# How to keep pointers to structures stored in vector valid?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, structure, realloc

I am learning C++ and I have trouble with pointers to structures stored in vector. The problem is that I need to keep the structure Student sorted twice. Once by student's id and another time by student's name, so it is easy to search the values in it. Because of this I created two vectors of pointers:

```
vector<Student *> sortedByID;    
vector<Student *> sortedByName;
```

The structure looks like this and I keep it in vector as well (even though it is probably not a good idea):

```
struct Student {
    int id;
    string name;
};

vector <Student> students;
```

I am creating the new struct with push_back and filling it with parameters from a function (yes, I have a constructor). To keep the vector of pointers sorted I am using lower_bound as shown below:

```
students.push_back(Student(id, name));
it = lower_bound(sortedByID.begin(), sortedByID.end(), id, cmp());
sortedByID.insert(it, &(students.back()));
//the same for name
```

The problem is that everytime I add the structure with push_back it reallocs new vector and destroys the address of previous objects, so pointers in vector sortedByID point to invalid value. I think it would be the same with an array of structs, because once the array is full, there is no other way (as far as I know) to resize it, than to create a new array and copy all the data from previous one (so the address will change again).

Is there any clever way to solve this problem? Please note that I am only allowed to use vector and not any other containers from STL.

Comment: You cannot, rather go with indices for such case. These won't change, even if the vector reallocates it's internal array.

Comment: You can make the sorted-vectors be vectors of integers that index into `students`. Of course then you have to make sure not to remove from the middle of `students` without recalculating your sort.

Comment: You are only allowed to use `vector`, huh? Does not seem like a real world problem does it? :rolleyes:

Comment: Please include enough of the code to constitute an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This also depends on how often the `vector` array is actually manipulated. If it's only populated once and you know the size of the vector or array beforehand then the memory addresses won't change location

Comment: @mainactual No, it's a part of school project, which I modified so it is easier to understand.

Comment: I could guess :). Like Christophe's 3), I'd use  `std::map< int, std::shared_ptr<Student> >` and `std::multimap< std::string, std::shared_ptr<Student> >`. That answer the question of keeping the pointers valid. `vector`ization is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

There are three options to solve this issue using only vectors and no other containers:

1) Avoid the reallocation.  This can only be achieved if you know the maximum M of expected number of elements to be inserted in your vector. In this case you can [`students.reserve(M);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/).

2) Forget the the pointers for `sortedByID` and `sortedByName`.  Use integers (or better said `size_t`) store the index of a student in `students` instead of a pointer. This supposes of course that the order of items in students is never changed.

3) Do not store the students themselves in a vector, but make `students` a vector of pointers to students (unsorted) that are allocated from free store.  If this alternative meets all your criteria, i'd suggest to go fore [`shared_ptr<Student>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: 1) I don't know final number of elements in the structure, but there are thousands of them. 2) I might try to do it this way, however it is not guaranteed that some of the students will not be deleted (I would say that it is guaranteed that they will be....). So I need to find a way how to check and sort the structure again. The idea behind this was to keep it sorted so binary search would be possible to implement. I need to work with the values in structure relatively fast (max O(log n)).

Comment: If you encapsulate your data structure in a class, you could well control deletion and envisage to insert students in a different order than sequential. Using indexes would make this very handy to implement as in the sorted vectors you could easily find the indexes to remove and the indexes to adjust.